# jqgrid - how can I change search parameters?

Tags: search, jqgrid

I use standard search from navGrid toolbar (magnifier picture). I have found some ways to manipulate search, but nothing works... I just need to short options list to equal, less and more...

Comment: what do you mean by search , list filter ?

Comment: Do you want to set the searching filter and start the searching or something other? It can be that you search for `sopt` property in the `searchoptions` option of the `colModel`. Do you read [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs#searching)? If it will not help, then you can modify the text of your question and describe more clear what the problem is and what you are looking for.

Comment: I have standard jqGrid. On bottom I have div with pager, search, reload, add and so on. When i click on search I have modal window. There are columns I set searchable and list of operators (equal and so on). I just want to modify this list. I use documentation http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator but or I do something wrong or this just not working...

Comment: OK I understand now where your problem is. I'll write an answer soon. Please use @Oleg in the text of comment to notify me that you wrote something to me. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You receive the Search button in the navigation toolbar with respect of [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator) jqGrid method. The method create for you some standard buttons. You can specify which buttons you want include with respect of the next `navGrid` parameters. For example,

```
jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid('navGrid','#gridpager',
                          {add:false,edit:false,del:false});
```

will add only "Refresh" (Reload) and "Search" buttons in the navigation toolbar. If the user click on one from the buttons the corresponding jqGrid method will be called. In case of "Add" and "Edit" operation if will be [editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#editgridrow) method. In case of "Delete" button it will be [delGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#delgridrow) method, in case of "Search" button it will be [searchGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asinge_searching#calling_conventions) method and in case of "View" button it will be [viewGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#viewgridrow) method. All from the methods has different parameters and events. To define the optons/parameters of the methods you can use additional parameters of the [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator). For example, to use "Advanced Searching" dialog with custom searching options you can use the following form of the 'navGrid' call:

```
jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid('navGrid','#gridpager',
                          {add:false,edit:false,del:false}, // navGrid options
                          {},
                          {},
                          {},
                          {multipleSearch:true, sopt:['eq','ne','bw','cn']});
```

In the most cased one don't change the common search rules per `sopt`. Instead of that one uses `sopt` property of the [searchoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asearch_config#colmodel_options) property in the [colModel](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acolmodel_options). In the way you can define different set of search rules for different columns.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was the part I was missing.

Comment: @Oleg: What happens when a custom editfunc is added in this example? I am wrestling trying to get that to work.  That is to say, both having search parameters and an editfunc I cannot get to work.

Comment: @Roadowl: It's better that you open new question, where you describe more detailed what you need to implement and what you tried. It's important to write which version of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). One don't need to use `editfunc` in the most cases. It's enough typically to use `beforeShowForm` or `afterShowForm`. I could try to help you, but I need to understand what you try to implement.